# Filter list data using SPServices, CAML Query, and dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, jquery, caml-query, spservices

I'm trying to create a table using SPServices to fetch the data, and filter it using CAML Query and a drop down list. I would like to create three conditions:

A. If no item from the list is selected, well nothing happens (This part is working)

B. Select a a Fiscal Year from dropdown_a and Regional Office from dropdown_b. This part is working also, and this is query I'm using:

```
   CamlQuery = "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /><Value Type='Text'>"+regionalOffice+"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' /><Value Type='Text'>"+fiscalYear+"</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>";
```

[image]

C. Now I would like to create a third option where if you select "All" in dropdown_a (Fiscal Year), it would list item from all the year for the office selected in dropdown_b. This is what I have done so far with no luck:

```
CamlQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office'><Value Type='Text'>"+regionalOffice+"</FieldRef></Eq></Where></Query>";
```

For some reason it is not showing my code, this is an screen shot:

[image]

Any ideas why this third option is not working? Thanks!

I apologize, but for some reason the code I pasted kept deleting themselves, so I have to add them as images.

Comment: It is not deleting, you must make sure to use the brackets icon in the RTE-panel to mark them as code. Simple do a couple of blank rows, paste in your code, select it and then click the "{ }" icon above the input field

Comment: That's the way I did it when I posted the question. It showed only when I changed the conditions I listed from 1, 2, 3 to A, B, C. I don't know why.

Comment: If you use 1.2.3. you need to indent the code by 4 more blanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked with the query:

```
 CamlQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /><Value Type='Text'>" + regionalOffice + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
```

This will show all the items that match "regionalOffice".

I also had to add a:

```
 $("#myTable").remove();
```

I know all this would had been a lot easier using the Datatables jQuery plugin, but I went to a lot of pain just to be allowed to use jQuery and SPservices. Thank you all for the comments, specially @SP Combatant.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the working query it's difficult to compare the two.

When troubleshooting it can be helpful to replace `<Eq>` with `<Neq>` or `<Contains>`

If no results are returned then it may alert you to a problem elsewhere.

Comment: SP Combatant. Thank you for the comments. I added the code from the beginning but it kept deleting itself. I have edited the question. Hopefully it wont go away again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your "regionalOffice" closing tag. It is `<FieldRef>` it needs to be `</Value>`.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that, but still doesn't work: `CamlQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office'><Value Type='Text'>"+regionalOffice+"</Value></FieldRef></Eq></Where></Query>"`

Comment: By matching it to your working CAML, I think you can self-close the field ref tag, so it looks like this -
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /><Value Type='Text'>"+regionalOffice+"</Value></Eq>

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good example that hopefully help you with the query:

```
http://sympmarc.com/2010/09/29/real-life-example-with-spservices-telephone-list-gadget/
```

Comment: Please add more details from the link to your post, if the link breaks it will be of no help to future readers

Answer (score 0):

**spservices** admits the `CamlQuery` option but only adds your caml query as a **fragment**.  You don't add the entire query, just the part that goes within the `<Add>` tags - you don't even add the `<Add>` tags OR specify which field - just add the innards.  The spservices function takes care of setting which field for the lookup.  You won't realize that [unless you read the docs very carefully](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown).

See my [post here for a working example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164174/7452) of a filter.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Testmysite/Style Library/empoylee/jquery-2.2.3.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Testmysite/Style Library/empoylee/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js">
</script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btn").click(function() {
            //debugger;
            var input = $('#wt2').val();
            var input2 = $('#wt3').val();

            read(input, input2);
        });

    });

    function read(input, input2) {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: "http://wfzo-pc:19684/sites/Testmysite",
            listName: "Employee",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Designation' /><Value Type='Text'>" + input + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/><Value Type='Text'>" + input2 + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>",
            //CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Designation' /><Value Type='Text'>"+input+"<FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>"+input2+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

                    var Name = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                    var Designation = $(this).attr("ows_Designation");
                    var Department = $(this).attr("ows_Department");
                    var age = $(this).attr("ows_age");
                    var tbldata = "<tr><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + Designation + "</td><td>" + Department + "</td><td>" + age + "</td></tr>"
                    $("#tbl1").append(tbldata);


                });

            }
        });
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btn2").click(function() {
            // debugger;
            var input3 = $('#wt4').val();
            readage(input3);
        });
    });

    function readage(input3) {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: "http://wfzo-pc:19684/sites/Testmysite",
            listName: "Employee",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='age' /><Value Type='Text'>" + input3 + "</Value></Leq></Where></Query>",
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

                    var Name = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                    var Designation = $(this).attr("ows_Designation");
                    var Department = $(this).attr("ows_Department");
                    var age = $(this).attr("ows_age");
                    var tbldata = "<tr><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + Designation + "</td><td>" + Department + "</td><td>" + age + "</td></tr>"
                    $("#tbl1").append(tbldata);


                });

            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="tbldatamain">
    <table id="tbl1" border="1px">
        <tr>



            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>age</th>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input id="wt2" type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
<input id="wt3" type="text" placeholder="Department" />
<input id="wt4" type="text" placeholder="age" />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Search" />
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="check-age" />
```

Comment: Can you please add some description, and explain your answer. Just code will not be helpful.